# DAX query with sub-query and IF ELSE

Tags: powerbi, dax

New to DAX, I'm trying to create a below DAX query, however, I'm not sure how to go about, I've a measure (selected value by user) using which I want to pass to the query, and using that measure I want to pass dynamic parameters to a filter. Below is what I want to achieve.

`TABLE_SUM = 
CALCULATE(SUM('TABLE'[Total]),
FILTER('TABLE',
'TABLE'[Filter_1] = [Selected-val-1] &&
'TABLE'[Filter_2] = "CONSTANT1" &&
'TABLE'[Filter_3] = "CONSTANT2" &&
'TABLE'[Filter_4] IN (IF ([Selected-val-2] =="All", DISTINCT('TABLE'[Filter_4]),[Selected-val-2])))
)`

IF `all` is selected then I want distinct values of  `'TABLE'[Filter_4]` else I want to pass `[Selected-val-2]`?

I get `is not a valid table` error... if I remove If else condition and only apply the true condition inside `IN` clause,  I don't get the error, but it doesn't solve my purpose.

Comment: you have an unnecessary ) here: 'TABLE'[Filter_3] = "CONSTANT2")

Comment: it's a typo in the question, I've fixed it. would you know how to go about it?

Comment: what's the formula for [Selected-val-2]?

Comment: Selected-val-2= `SELECTEDVALUE('TABLE2'[Filter_4],"All")`

Comment: TABLE2 is a disconnected table?

Comment: yeah but the `filter_4` has same values in both the tables.

Comment: Try to replace the last line with this: 'TABLE'[Filter_4] IN DISTINCT('TABLE2'[Filter_4]).

Comment: it will work but how do I add the if condition? If `All` not selected then I need to pass selected value

Comment: it should achieve the same result without IF

Comment: not exactly, ok, I found `ISFILTERED` option that allows me to check if the value was filtered or not , if not then apply the condition. 
`TABLE_SUM = 
CALCULATE(SUM('TABLE'[Total]),
FILTER('TABLE',
'TABLE'[Filter_1] = [Selected-val-1] &&
'TABLE'[Filter_2] = "CONSTANT1" &&
'TABLE'[Filter_3] = "CONSTANT2" &&
( NOT (ISFILTERED('TABLE2'[Filter_4])) ||
'TABLE'[Filter_4]= [Selected-val-2]))))
)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is that the false result in your `IF` returns a scalar rather than a table. `'TABLE'[Filter_4] IN <Some Scalar>` isn't valid DAX. You might be able to fix this by replacing the last `[Selected-val-2]` with a single element list, `{ [Selected-val-2] }`.

@RADO is correct that you can refactor that last line.

```
'TABLE'[Filter_4]
    IN (
        IF (
            [Selected-val-2] == "All",
            DISTINCT ( 'TABLE'[Filter_4] ),
            [Selected-val-2]
        )
    )
```

Let's look at the two cases: `'TABLE'[Filter_4]` has (1) one value or (2) has multiple values (or no values). Then the above reduces to

---

(1) The condition `[Selected-val-2] == "All"` is false:

```
'TABLE'[Filter_4] IN [Selected-val-2]
```

Since `SELECTEDVALUE ( 'TABLE2'[Filter_4], "All" )` is equivalent to

`IF ( HASONEVALUE ( 'TABLE2'[Filter_4] ), VALUES ( 'TABLE2'[Filter_4] ), "All" )`, since we are in case (1), this reduces to

```
'TABLE'[Filter_4] IN VALUES ( 'TABLE2'[Filter_4] )
```

---

(2) The condition `[Selected-val-2] == "All"` is true:

```
'TABLE'[Filter_4] IN  DISTINCT ( 'TABLE'[Filter_4] )
```

---

Both of these are [basically equivalent](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2011/03/08/difference-between-distinct-and-values-in-dax/) to `'TABLE'[Filter_4] IN  DISTINCT ( 'TABLE'[Filter_4] )`.